# How to have the actionbar above tab bar and order items in actionbar with actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to have an actionbar without title and icon with 2 buttons: ok and erase. I know how to do that but I have 2 questions:

1. If there's no image nor title, the bar is below the tab bar (or at least this is what the demo does). How can be above the tab bar? Or do you think is better to have this action bar at the bottom of the app? If so, can you explain me how to put it down? Because I don't understand the demo (may be is too simple)
2. How can be the ok button always on the right and the erase on the left? (just as split action items in the demo but with the space of the button of search in blank)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Finally I put it at the bottom. You have to put in addition in your manifest:

   ```
   <activity android:name=".yourclass" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"></activity>
   ```
2. I erased the code for the button in the sample and the result was as I wanted